# не пойму как сделать задание с елочкой. паскаль

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

У меня не получается понять задание:

> Пользователь вводит число N>0. Программа печатает N строк, содержащих символ "*", расположенные таким образом, чтобы результат был похож на на елочку:

```
*
**
***
*****
********
```

Просто решил подучить delphi, но для начала взял паскальabc.net, чтобы основы подучить. Но вот попалось задание, в котором мне не понятно именно как должно отображаться. Прошу подсказать как это можно написать, можно код даже на c#. Просто не могу понять как увеличивается в строке 4 на два символа *, а в следующей еще больше.

Вот код который у меня:

```
var N:=readinteger('N=');
begin
  for var i:=1 to N do 
    begin
    for var j:=1 to i do
    begin
      write('*');
      end;
      writeln();
    end;
end.
```

Вывод моего кода:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: Наверное, количество выводимых звездочек должно увеличиваться на величину, зависящую от номера строки. Точнее не скажешь, пока задача не поставлена чётко.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, может станет понятнее...

Comment: @MBo к сожалению это все условие задачи. Большего найти не смог.

Comment: @SwaD я добавил код

Comment: В задании количество звездочек больше на последовательность Фибоначчи  походит, хотя я сомневаюсь, что кто-то именно этот смысл туда закладывал

Comment: @Михаил Ребров Кстати да, вполне возможно, но данных маловато.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var len := 1;
for var i:=1 to N do 
begin
  for var j:=1 to len do 
    write('*');
  writeln();
  //А может, StringOfChar есть в этом pascalabc.net?

  if i = 1 then
    len := len + 1
  else 
    len:= len + i - 1;
end;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Comment: подобный stringofchar есть в паскале.

Comment: Тогда можно writeln(stringofchar.. заменить три строчки выше

Comment: хорошо, я подправлю, спасибо за ответ